# Saving array rows in my sql

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Example:

Controller

```
$code = $_POST['book'][0]['code'];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if(!empty($code)) {
        $insertdata['code'] = $code;
    } else {
        $insertdata['code'] = null;
    }
}

$code = $_POST['book'][1]['code'];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if(!empty($code)) {
        $insertdata2['code'] = $code;
    } else {
        $insertdata2['code'] = null;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
$this->db->insert('ap_entry', $insertdata, $insertdata2);
```

Details.
     I need to save this two rows in one table. In my database i'll set id as my PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: and what's the `for loop` for??

Comment: How to do a one array and insert that array?? C0dekid?

Comment: To limit it into < 5 entry. Fu Xu.